# Pandas fill nan values with a split of the first available value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace nan values in a DataFrame with a split of the first previous available value across all the following nan values.

In the example below :

```
import pandas as pd
df = [100, None, None, 40, None, 120]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to get :

```
[33.33, 33.33, 33.33, 20, 20, 120]
```

If I could find a way to count the number of nan values following each value in my column, then I could run some computations to achieve the split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = [100, None, None, 40, None, 120]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['a'])

s = df['a'].ffill() / df.groupby(df['a'].notna().cumsum())['a'].transform('size')
print (s)

0     33.333333
1     33.333333
2     33.333333
3     20.000000
4     20.000000
5    120.000000
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

**Details**:

You can replace missing value by previous non `NaN`s values by `ffill`:

```
print (df['a'].ffill())
0    100.0
1    100.0
2    100.0
3     40.0
4     40.0
5    120.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Then compare by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['a'].notna().cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

And get counts per groups with same size like original with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
print (df.groupby(df['a'].notna().cumsum())['a'].transform('size'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: By any chance, could you also provide a solution in case the dataframe has also a column called 'category', and I would like to apply exactly your solution but after doing a kind off df.groupby('category').apply(your_solution_for_each_group)

Comment: @Waroulolz use `s = df.groupby('category')['a'].ffill() / df.groupby(['category', df['a'].notna().cumsum()] )['a'].transform('size')
print (s)`, om phone only, so not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an `ffill`, and get the first column, and divide it by it (the `ffill`ed dataframe) `groupby`ed and use `transform('count')` to get the counts and keep the same length for the dataframe:

```
print(df.ffill()[0] / df.ffill().groupby(0)[0].transform('count'))
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195510/discussion-between-jezrael-and-u9-forward).

Comment: @U9-Forward Looks nice now :)