# Pandas code to PySpark with groupby operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

In pandas I achieved to transform the following, which is basically splitting the first non null value across following null values.

`[100, None, None, 40, None, 120]`

into

`[33.33, 33.33, 33.33, 20, 20, 120]`

Thanks to the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753303/pandas-fill-nan-values-with-a-split-of-the-first-available-value?answertab=votes#tab-top), I managed to produce the following code for my specific task:

```
cols = ['CUSTOMER', 'WEEK', 'PRODUCT_ID']
colsToSplit = ['VOLUME', 'REVENUE']
df = pd.concat([
    d.asfreq('W')
    for _, d in df.set_index('WEEK').groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'PRODUCT_ID'])
]).reset_index()
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
df['nb_nan'] = df.groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'PRODUCT_ID', df_sellin['VOLUME'].notnull().cumsum()])['VOLUME'].transform('size')
df[colsToSplit] = df.groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'PRODUCT_ID'])[colsToSplit].ffill()[colsToSplit].div(df.nb_nan, axis=0)
df
```

My full dataframe looks like this :

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(map(list, zip(*[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
           ['2018-01-14', '2018-01-28', '2018-01-14', '2018-01-28', '2018-01-14', '2018-02-04', '2018-02-11', '2018-01-28', '2018-02-11'],
           [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
           [50, 44, 22, 34, 42, 41, 43, 12, 13],
           [15, 14, 6, 11, 14, 13.5, 13.75, 3, 3.5]])), columns =['CUSTOMER', 'WEEK', 'PRODUCT_ID', 'VOLUME', 'REVENUE']) 

 df
Out[16]: 
      CUSTOMER        WEEK  PRODUCT_ID  VOLUME  REVENUE
    0        a  2018-01-14           1      50    15.00
    1        a  2018-01-28           1      44    14.00
    2        a  2018-01-14           2      22     6.00
    3        a  2018-01-28           2      34    11.00
    4        b  2018-01-14           1      42    14.00
    5        b  2018-02-04           1      41    13.50
    6        b  2018-02-11           1      43    13.75
    7        c  2018-01-28           3      12     3.00
    8        c  2018-02-11           3      13     3.50
```

In this case for example, the result would be :

```
CUSTOMER        WEEK  PRODUCT_ID  VOLUME  REVENUE
a         2018-01-14           1      25     7.50
a         2018-01-21           1      25     7.50
a         2018-01-28           1      44    14.00
a         2018-01-14           2      11     3.00
a         2018-01-21           2      11     3.00
a         2018-01-28           2      34    11.00
b         2018-01-14           1      14     4.67
b         2018-01-21           1      14     4.67
b         2018-01-28           1      14     4.67
b         2018-02-04           1      41    13.50
b         2018-02-11           1      43    13.75
c         2018-01-28           3       6     1.50
c         2018-02-04           3       6     1.50
c         2018-02-11           3      13     3.50
```

Sadly, my dataframe is way too big for further use and joins with other datasets, therefore I would like to test it out with Spark. I checked out many tutorials to compute most of those steps in PySpark, but none of them really showed how to include the groupby part. So I found how to do a transform('size') but not how to df.groupby(...).transform('size') and how I can combine all my steps.

Is there maybe a tool that can do pandas to PySpark translation ? Otherwise, could I have a clue on how to translate this piece of code ? Thanks, maybe I'm just over complicating this.

Comment: How is VOLUME populated? Can you show what your final desired output is and explain the steps in more detail?

Comment: I just added the full result dataframe

Comment: How do you know which weeks are missing? Why isn't `2018-01-07` "missing"? Why stop at Feb 11?

Comment: all weeks between first and last week should be present. So for each Customer/Product_ID, the weeks missing are all the ones between the very first and very last date